# cfloop empty query condition?

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I have the following ColdFusion code that is getting information from a database and displaying the results on the homepage. Here's the cfquery code:

```
<cfquery name="getSchedule" datasource="#APPLICATION.datasource#" dbtype="odbc">
SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE_Days SD 
LEFT JOIN SCHEDULE_ScheduledClasses SSC ON SD.day_id = SSC.day_id
LEFT JOIN SCHEDULE_Classes SC ON SSC.class_id = SC.class_id
WHERE SD.day_date = #createODBCDate(now())# AND SSC.schedule_cancelled = 0
ORDER BY SSC.start_time
</cfquery>
```

and the output code:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="getSchedule">
<tr>
<td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="74">#lcase(timeFormat(start_time,"h:mm tt"))#</td>
<td width="158">#class_name#</td>
</tr>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

The issue is, if there is no data contained within getSchedule (i.e., there are no ScheduledClasses), it displays nothing.

I'm looking for a way to change this so that, in the event that there is no data to display, I can specify a message and code to be shown in its absence.

Comment: Reading the docs on CFQUERY (or even CFLOOP, as there's a comment covering it in the footnotes) would have allowed you to answer this for yourself.  -1, sorry.

Comment: The candor is appreciated Adam - I inherited this code base and couldn't know less about ColdFusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First just a quick CF tip you can make you code better by doing it this way:

```
<cfif getSchedule.recordcount GT 0>
    <cfoutput query="getSchedule">
    <tr>
        <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="74">#lcase(timeFormat(getSchedule.start_time,"h:mm tt"))#</td>
        <td width="158">#getSchedule.class_name#</td>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <p>Empty record message here</p>
</cfif>
```

The reason I put the query output first is most likely this will happen more than with your empty set message.

Comment: This will produce invalid HTML - you can't have a `P` inside a `TABLE`. Probably want to use `<tr><td colspan="3" class="no-schedule">...msg...</td></tr>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfif getSchedule.recordcount>
.... do something
</cfif>
```

Will work just aswell there is no need for gt 0

Answer (score 0):

Use the recordCount to detect whether the query has any record

```
<cfif getSchedule.recordcount gt 0>
.... do something
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfif getSchedule.RecordCount>
<table>
<cfoutput query="getSchedule">
<tr>
<td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="74">#lcase(timeFormat(start_time,"h:mm tt"))#</td>
<td width="158">#class_name#</td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
<cfelse>
<p>There are currently no records</p>
</cfif>
```